# How can I set some initial properties on a ModelAdmin class based on request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have this class:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
        ....

    def delete_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
        ....
```

basically I keep repeating `if request.user.is_superuser`.  What I want is to set an initial flag so that I can keep reusing that.  Why?  Because the logic could change to `if request.user.is_superuser or ...` and I don't want to have to repeat that everywhere.  I looked at `__init__()` and could not really see a way to do what I want.

Comment: What should happen in the `else` case?

Comment: Something like using a different model manager but that's not really what I'm asking (just clarifying, not saying that in a rude way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to just create a function on the PersonAdmin, maybe something like has_permission.

```py
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if self.has_permission(request.user):
        ....

    def delete_queryset(self, request):
        if self.has_permission(request.user):
        ....

    def has_permission(self, user):
        # later at other logic
        return user.is_superuser
```

Comment: I get what you did there and maybe it is the best solution for my specific case but I was hoping to find a hook where my logic could go so that I follow the intended flow.  With this solution, I'll have to rely on a user being passed in so it does not make it very reusable if I change my logic to not requiring a user permission.

Comment: If you don't want to pass in the user, but want to user when needed. You can check out this Django app https://pypi.org/project/django-middleware-global-request/, with that you could the user with get_request().user

Comment: I like this answer, maybe give a different name to the function and not override the has_permission func. @Pittfall u r using the request as well. "if request.user.is_superuser:" so i do not get your concern.

Comment: Simple solution but I was blocked by some other thoughts I had on the matter.  However, this is the way to go.